# Converting geometry into Bones

Tags: mesh, armature, conversion

Bones to mesh ISN'T what I'm hoping for. I thought this would be easy but I have Objects that follow simple rigid body physics and the lame fish shape. Can't I deform the fish using those box shapes as Bones?

[image: Basic meshes as bones]

The goal, perhaps you see, is ragdoll-like meshes, not just ragdoll boxes.

Comment: it's not clear to me, do you mean that you don't want any bone, you want these boxes to act like bones?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping for envelope weights or some such Parenting.